# Dreamweaver PHP contact form returning name error

Tags: php

So for an assignment we need a contact form, the basic form was provided by my teacher but mine keeps returning with "Please correct the following error:
Enter your name you tit!" when I click submit. Everything else on my website is working fine, but this form is making me pull my hair out! Any help is greatly appreciated. (fake@fake.com on the form has been changed to my real address)

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = "Fake@fake.com";
$subject = "Order Form - B Bakery";
$name = check_input($_POST['name'],"Enter your name you tit!");
$Email    = check_input($_POST['Email'],"Enter your email you tit!");
$Phone   = check_input($_POST['Phone']);
$Message = check_input($_POST['Message'],"Enter your message you tit!");
/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
    show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}

/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "Hello!

Your contact form has been submitted by:

Name: $name
E-mail: $Email
Phone: $Phone

Message:
$Message

End of message
";
/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: thankyou.html');
exit();
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
    <body>

    <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
    <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Order Form</title>

<style type="text/css">
#wrapper #ddffdd {
    position: absolute;
    height: 500px;
    width: 929px;
    left: 385px;
    top: 230px;
    background: #FFF;
}

body {
    background-image: url(Pics/pink-floral-background.jpg);
    background-repeat;
    }

#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 500px;
}

#menu ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    height: auto;
    padding-left: 17px;
    border-right-width: thin;
    border-left-width: thin;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-right-color: #000;
    border-left-color: #000;
    border-top-width: thin;
    border-bottom-width: thin;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-top-color: #000;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    padding-right: 17px;
}

#menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 399px;
    top: 1px;
    width: 737px;
}
#menu {
    height: 27px;
    width: 764px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 29px;
    top: 170px;
}

#HomeText {
    position: absolute;
    left: 305px;
    top: 9px;
    width: 520px;
    alignment: absolute;
    height: 53px;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
}
#cakepic {
    position: absolute;
    left: 3px;
    top: 24px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
#HomeText2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 47px;
    top: 91px;
    width: 192px;
    alignment: absolute;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
    height: 385px;
}
#HomeText3 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 478px;
    top: 91px;
    width: 192px;
    alignment: absolute;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
    height: 385px;
}
#Banner{
    height: 90px;
    width: 800px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    left: 325px;
}
#Banner #Bannertop {
    position: absolute;
    left: 237px;
    top: -34px;
}
#Banner #Bannerbottom img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 381px;
    top: 57px;
}
#wrapper #Banner div form table tr td {
    text-align: right;
}
#wrapper #Banner div form table {
    text-align: left;
}
#wrapper #ddffdd form table {
    position: absolute;
    left: 11px;
    top: 124px;
    width: 901px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_validateForm() { //v4.0
  if (document.getElementById){
    var i,p,q,nm,test,num,min,max,errors='',args=MM_validateForm.arguments;
    for (i=0; i<(args.length-2); i+=3) { test=args[i+2]; val=document.getElementById(args[i]);
      if (val) { nm=val.name; if ((val=val.value)!="") {
        if (test.indexOf('isEmail')!=-1) { p=val.indexOf('@');
          if (p<1 || p==(val.length-1)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain an e-mail address.\n';
        } else if (test!='R') { num = parseFloat(val);
          if (isNaN(val)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number.\n';
          if (test.indexOf('inRange') != -1) { p=test.indexOf(':');
            min=test.substring(8,p); max=test.substring(p+1);
            if (num<min || max<num) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number between '+min+' and '+max+'.\n';
      } } } else if (test.charAt(0) == 'R') errors += '- '+nm+' is required.\n'; }
    } if (errors) alert('The following error(s) occurred:\n'+errors);
    document.MM_returnValue = (errors == '');
} }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class=header></div>
        <div id="menu">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="FAQ.html">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="Order Form.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="Latest News.html">Latest News</li>
        <li><a href="Product List.html">Product List</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
<p></p>
<div id="Banner">
  <p>

  <div id="Bannertop"> <img src="coollogo_com-201093071.png" width="409" height="83" /></div></p>
<p>
<div id="Bannerbottom"><img src="coollogo_com-200791182.png" width="406" height="34" />
</div>
<div>

</div>
</div>
<div id="ddffdd">
  <div id=HomeText>Contact</div>

  <form action="myform.php" method="get">
    <table width="99%" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td width="33%" onfocus="MM_validateForm('name','','R','Phone','','RisNum','Email','','RisEmail');return document.MM_returnValue"><label for="name">
          <div align="right" onfocus="MM_validateForm('name','','R','Phone','','RisNum','Email','','RisEmail','Message','','R');return document.MM_returnValue">Name</div>
        </label>        </td>
        <td width="67%"><div align="left">
          <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="36" />
        </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="Phone">
          <div align="right">Phone Number</div>
        </label>
          <label for="Email">
            <div align="right">Email</div>
          </label></td>
        <td><div align="left">
          <input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone" />
        </div>
<input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div align="right">Message</div></td>
        <td><div align="left">
          <textarea name="Message" id="Message" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div align="right">
          <input type="reset" name="Reset2" id="Reset2" value="Reset" />
        </div></td>
        <td><div align="left">
          <input name="Reset" type="submit" id="Reset" onclick="MM_validateForm('name','','R','Phone','','RisNum','Email','','RisEmail');return document.MM_returnValue" value="Submit" />
        </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div align="right"></div></td>
        <td><div align="right"></div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have recieved an email :D but afterwards it goes to my webhost 404 and not my thankyou page, THANK YOU SO MUCH!

IT IS WORKING :DDDDDDDDDD thank you very much everyone, I owe you all a beer!

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious but have you entered your name? (You tit..)

Comment: Showing the form code may help.

Comment: Please post the form markup.

Comment: Can you provide the FORM being submitted?

Comment: Based on the code style your form name field is ``Name`` (with uppercase). Anyways to correct this please post form html.

Comment: Working on answer changes, thank you very much for your help so far, will post results if working

Comment: Those unfriendly error messages may scare away customers... (You tit.)

Comment: See @ErickBest 's answer... it will solve your problem!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iF YOU USE...PHP's `$_POST`, your `<form method` has to be something like..

```
<form method='POST'
```

IF you  use PHP's `$_GET`, your `<form method` has to be something like..

```
<form method='GET'
```

So, here in you code:

```
$name = check_input($_POST['name'],"Enter your name you tit!");
$Email    = check_input($_POST['Email'],"Enter your email you tit!");
$Phone   = check_input($_POST['Phone']);
$Message = check_input($_POST['Message'],"Enter your message you tit!");
```

The corresponding HTML  should be,

```
<form action="myform.php" method="POST"
```

for it to work.

Comment: Yeah, just dont forget the closing `>` on the form element... see my edit

Comment: Right, Done all changes in current answers, now it is saying "Please correct the following error: E-mail address not valid" when I click submit

Comment: INSTEAD of: `if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email)){show_error("E-mail address not valid");` Why don't you go for the in built PHP functions?... Something like: `$email=filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)` and then::.. `if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ echo'No a Good Email';} else{ echo  'a Good Email';}....`... Try that to validate your Email and see how it works

Comment: got a syntax error on the if 
(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ echo'Not a Good Email';} else{ echo 'a Good Email';}

Comment: WHAT's the Error Saying??... Please read it... MAKE SURE You type it like... `if ( !filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ) { echo 'No Good Email';}` else{ echo 'Good Email'} Notice the Braces well

Comment: Not sure what the error is saying tbh, just saying there is an error and I copied and pasted it, so it is exactly the same

Comment: Right, I am receiving the email, thank you very much, I owe you a beer

Answer (score 0):

Change the form method to method="POST" instead of GET:

```
<form action="myform.php" method="POST">
```

Right now in the PHP code that processes the form input you are referring to the POST data. Right now you're using method is GET and that's why the values will not be set in the $_POST array. Alternatively in your processing code you could use $_GET instead of $_POST.

Comment: You're welcome. As for your second problem (the e-mail address) that's actually a separate question. What e-mail address do you fill out in the form? And what does var_dump($email) return when you do that right before the preg_match check?

Comment: One thing in the regular expression I notice is the escaping of the dash character, which is unnecessary. You can just write [\w-]+ instead of [\w\-]+. This will allow letters, digits, underscores and dashes.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `check_input`:

```
$name = check_input($_POST['name'],"Enter your name you tit!");
```

But when looking closer at the function I see

```
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
    show_error($problem);
}
```

However, as `$data=$_POST['name']`, the length and thus `strlen($data) != 0`

Why not just leave the whole if-statement out?

Oh: also change it to `method="post"`

Comment: if statement removed, tyvm for help